# IMPALA - How to get range partition size

Tags: impala, apache-kudu, range-partitions

For Parquet table I use `SHOW FILES IN db_name.parquet_table_name` to get all my partitions names, size and path for my Parquet table.

For Range partitions I use `SHOW RANGE PARTITIONS db_name.kudu_table_name` This give me only the partitons ranges but not the size.

How can I get partitions ranges and sizes for each to be able `to optimize my partitions ranges`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impala doesn't expose this via SQL.

I'm not an expert on the Kudu tooling. The various Kudu web UIs do have a wealth of data about the tablets and I suspect you can get this info through the Kudu command line tools as well - https://kudu.apache.org/docs/command_line_tools_reference.html#_command_hierarchy